# Scylla counter support in docker

Tags: docker, scylla

How can I enable counter support in Scylla running in a container (docker)? There are only few flags to modify addresses, but to enable counter support, we need to edit `scylla.yaml` and add `experimental: true` to the file. How can I edit the file which the scylla image uses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To enable counter support, use the scylla nightly image

```
sudo docker run --name docker-scylla -d -p 172.17.0.1:9042:9042 -p 172.17.0.1:9160:9160 -e broadcast_address=172.17.0.1  scylladb/scylla-nightly
```

As per Pekka's comment, Scylla 2.0 supports counters without anything special now that the feature is no longer experimental. Woop Woop!!

Comment: Scylla 2.0 supports counters without anything special now that the feature is no longer experimental.